# How to specify the object type in a generic method?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005

I have the following code to get the object type of a collection:

```
Dim objType As Type = myCollection.[GetType]().GetProperty("Item").PropertyType
```

That line seems to work, but then I need to convert the collection to a datatable specifying the type of the collection, what is the correct way to pass the object type as parameter?

I'm trying:

```
DataTableCollectionConverter.ConvertToDataTable(Of objType)(myCollection)
```

but it is not even recognized as valid code

I'm using VS 2005, Net 2.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables, even of type `Type`, in as type parameters for generics.  They have to be compiled up-front, not at run-time.  That's why the compiler is complaining.

You'll have to use a weakly-typed version of that method, rely on reflection in some way or use a switch statement to provide the right type parameter to the generic method.